# (Welsh chap3 q9) what is the pmf of the sum of $n$ Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability

> Welsh chap3 q9) Show by induction that the sum of $n$ independent random
>   variables, each having the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$,
>   has the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.

Proof:

Base case: $n=2$, let $X_1$ $X_2$ be two independent Bernoulli Random variables, then $X_1+X2$ is binomial with parameters $2$ and $p$.

Inductive step: suppose the claim is true for $n=k$, consider $n=k+1$, and we have $X_1,X_2,...,X_{k+1}$ $k+1$ independent Bernoulli random variables. So let $Z=\sum_i^{k+1}X_i$, and $Z_k=\sum_i^{k} X_i$ then $P(Z=z)=P(Z_k+X_{k+1}=z)=P(Z_k=(z-1))p+P(Z_k=(z))(1-p)=\binom{k}{z-1}p^z(1-p)^{k-z+1}+\binom{k}{z}p^z(1-p)^{k-z+1}=\binom{k+1}{z} p^z (1-p)^{k-z}$. which gives the answer.

**update**, miscalculation:

I still have one question, 1) is the sum of the first $k$ Bernoulli random variables 
$Z_k$ and the $k+1^th$ Bernoulli random variable $X_{k+1}$ independent? Because the proof above depends on that fact.

The definition of Binomial random variable Y with parameter $n$ and $p$ is $P(Y=y)=\binom{n}{y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}$ where $Y=0,1,2,...,n$

Comment: How are you defining the binomial distribution with parameters $p,n$?  I'd have said that this was, essentially, just the definition.

Comment: I edited the post and put the definition of Binomial random variable.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to show that that distribution gives you the number of successes in $n$ Bernoulli iterates (it being clear that the sum is also the number of successes).

Comment: Hint: You may consider using the Moment Generating Function approach

Comment: Ok I corrected an error and got the solution, however, I still don't know if the sum of the first $k$ Bernoulli random variables 
$Z_k$ and the $k+1^{th}$ Bernoulli random variable $X_{k+1}$ independent? Because the proof depends on that fact.

Comment: *Are the sum of the first $k$ Bernoulli random variables $Z_k$ and the $k+1$th Bernoulli random variable $X_{k+1}$ independent?* Yes: you are told  all the Bernoulli random variables are independent, and you can just use that fact.  The answer might have been "no" if you had only been told the Bernoulli random variables were *pairwise* independent

Comment: Cool, I was just worried that maybe taking sum of variables in a subset of a set of independent random variables somehow create a random variable that is not independent with the rest anymore.